# Is there a simple way of pairing unique data points in a data frame?

Tags: r, combinations

I want to extract pairs of data from a data frame, where they are paired with data that is not in their own column.  Each number in column 1 is paired with all the numbers to the right of that column.  Likewise numbers in column 2 are only paired with numbers in columns 3 or above.

I have created a script that does it using a bird's nest of 'for' loops but I feel there should be a more elegant way to do it.

Example data:

```
structure(list(A = 1:3, B = 4:6, C = 7:9), .Names = c("A", "B", 
          "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Desired output:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
          3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6), X2 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 
          8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 
          8, 9)), .Names = c("X1", "X2"), row.names = c(NA, 27L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach using `data.table` package and its very efficient `CJ` and `rbindlist` functions (assuming your data set called `df`)

```
library(data.table)
res <- rbindlist(lapply(seq_len(length(df) - 1), 
        function(i) CJ(df[, i], unlist(df[, -(seq_len(i))]))))
```

You could then set your column names by reference (if you insist on "X1" and "X2") using `setnames`

```
setnames(res, 1:2, c("X1", "X2"))
```

You can also convert back to `data.frame` by reference (if you want to match your desired output "exactly") by using `setDF()`

```
setDF(res)
```

Comment: Thank you - all the suggestions work, this seems the most elegant but I am struggling to fully grasp how any of them work.

Comment: @David Arenburg Indeed, this is elegant

Comment: This one is simple. We go thru all the columns (except the last one) and cross join them against the all the rest of the columns (from the current column to the end). When we use `unlist` we are basically converting the data frame to one column and cross joinng to it. Then we use `rbindlist` to put everything together

Answer (score 1):

Here `df` is the input `dataset`

```
out1 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:(ncol(df)-1), function(i) {
               x1 <- df[,i:(ncol(df))]
               Un1 <-unique(unlist(x1[,-1]))
           data.frame(X1=rep(x1[,1], each=length(Un1)), X2= Un1)}))

 all.equal(out, out1) #if `out` is the expected output
 #[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
res <- do.call(rbind, unlist(lapply(seq(ncol(dat) - 1), function(x) 
  lapply(seq(x + 1, ncol(dat)), function(y) 
    "names<-"(expand.grid(dat[c(x, y)]), c("X1", "X2")))),
  recursive = FALSE))
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

You can sort the result with this command:

```
res[order(res[[1]], res[[2]]), ]
```